# Can someone please explain this callback to me

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback

i don't understand what is being call-backed upon is it feeding itself the array the operation or what i just don't know where to start

```
function mySelect (arr, cb) {
      var selected = [];

      arr.forEach(function(ele, i, ar) {
        if (cb(ele, i, ar)) {
          selected.push(ele);
        }
      });

      return selected;
    }

    mySelect([1,2,3,4,5,6], function(ele, i, arr) {
        return (ele % 2 === 0);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code returns even numbers from an array, by the code:

```
ele % 2 === 0 //(test if even)
```

ie. if the ele (or number) is divivded by 2 and has no remainder

```js
function mySelect (arr, cb) // cb = callBackFunction
{
  var selected = [];

  arr.forEach(function(ele, i, ar)
  {
    if (cb(ele, i, ar)) // call back here tests if even
    {
      selected.push(ele);
    }
  });
  return selected;
}

var selected = mySelect([1,2,3,4,5,6], function(ele, i, arr)
{
  return (ele % 2 === 0);
});

console.log(selected);
```

The same code without the callback function, but with the even test embedded in the main function would be:

```js
function mySelect (arr) // no callBack Function
{
  var selected = [];

  arr.forEach(function(ele, i, ar)
  {
    if (ele % 2 === 0) // tests if even
    {
      selected.push(ele);
    }
  });
  return selected;
}

var selected = mySelect([1,2,3,4,5,6]);

console.log(selected);
```

I hope this helps :)